# How to add the hostname to every line of SystemOut.log?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-6.1

We have load balancing and the same name on multiple instances of WebSphere 6.1.

Is there a way to WebSphere need to add the physical hostname to the WebSphere SystemOut.log lines (for example, to prepend to every line)?

Thanks, Bert

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to see how the load is distributed across all the WAS Instances (in a cluster as you had mentioned load balancing)

Is that a web application that you are working with?

If yes the cloneID would give you the answers. Each Server in a cluster is given a unique clone ID.

Look at the Web Server's plugin logs and see which server received the request.

This can be used for a Web Application to see which server serviced the request.

HTH
Manglu

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [custom log formatter and handler](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rtrb_cbeusecustom.html) and attach them to the root logger. It should capture everything and you should be able to decide the complete logging format and location. The example is for 6.0 but the example should be still valid.

Alternatively you could implement similar log formatter and [configure the JVM logs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/utrb_jvmlogs.html) to use custom log format.